# How to handle multiple dialog boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a sort of mini gallery for myself as a personal project. I am displaying mini pictures and if i click on them, a modal should pop up displaying entire picture.

```
  <dialog>
    <img src="static/img/img (1).jpg" height="600">
    <button autofocus>Close</button>
  </dialog>
  <button class="btn">
    <img src="static/img/img (1).jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </button>
  
  <dialog>
    <img src="static/img/img (2).jpg" height="600">
  <button autofocus>Close</button>
  </dialog>
  <button class="btn">
    <img src="static/img/img (2).jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </button>
```

this is my html structure. There are many more pics, this is just the first two.

```
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
const showButton = document.querySelector("dialog + button");
const closeButton = document.querySelector("dialog button");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the dialog modally
showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
});

// "Close" button closes the dialog
closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
});
```

This is my js file.

Problem is first modal is working fine, but none of the other modal is working. How can I make it work?

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()` and loop through all elements.

Comment: It worked. querySelectorAll() and then looping through the list solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Reza and Dilraj can you submit and accept in question-and-answer form please?

Answer (score 1):

Using `querySelectorAll` =>

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
const showButton = document.querySelectorAll("dialog + button");
const closeButton = document.querySelectorAll("dialog button");

// "Show the dialog" button opens the dialog modally
showButton.forEach(k=> k.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.showModal();
}));

// "Close" button closes the dialog
closeButton.forEach(l=>l.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialog.close();
}));
```

```html
<dialog>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" height="600">
    <button autofocus>Close</button>
  </dialog>
  <button class="btn">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </button>
  
  <dialog>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" height="600">
  <button autofocus>Close</button>
  </dialog>
  <button class="btn">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" height="200" width="200">
  </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job

```
const dialogs = document.querySelectorAll("dialog");
const closeButton = document.querySelector("dialog button");
const imgButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

    imgButtons.forEach((button,index) => {
  console.log('hi')
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const dialog = dialogs[index]
    const dialogImage = dialog.querySelector("img");
    const imageSrc = button.querySelector("img").src;
    dialogImage.src = imageSrc;
    dialog.showModal();
  });
})
dialogs.forEach(dialog => {
  const closeButton = dialog.querySelector("button");
  closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.close();
  });
});
```